# MySQL stored procedure only returns records with child records

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, nested-if

I have a table, task, which has a foreign key in table, comment.

```
+-------------+   +-----------+
|Task         |   |Comment    |
+-------------+   +-----------+
|t_id (PK)    |   |c_id (PK)  |
|t_title      |   |c_task (FK)|
|t_description|   |c_comment  |
|t_state      |   |c_date     |
+-------------+   +-----------+
```

I need to get ALL tasks, AND date from last comment, IF THERE ARE ANY, AND i need to know what to order by OR eliminate records with a certain state. All in the same procedure.
My problem right now is that if i try that, i only get tasks with comments attached. If there are no comments attached to a task, it doesn't show.

```
create procedure getalltask(state boolean,  orderby varchar(30))
begin
IF state = true then
   select 
      t_id,  
      t_title, 
      t_description, 
      t_state,
      DATE_FORMAT(c_date, '%e/%c %H:%i') as c_datetime
   from task, comment
   where task.t_state = orderBy
      and task.t_id = comment.c_task
      and c_date IN 
   (
   select MAX(c_date) 
   from comment 
   where task.t_id = comment.c_task
      and MAX(c_id)
   )

ELSE
   select 
      t_id, 
      t_title, 
      t_description, 
      t_state, 
      DATE_FORMAT(c_date, '%e/%c %H:%i') as c_datetime,
      @nextid := DATE_FORMAT(c_date, '%e/%c %H:%i'),
      c_date
   from task, comment
      and task.t_id = taskcomment.c_task
      and c_date IN 
   (
   select MAX(c_date) 
   from comment 
   where task.t_id = comment.c_task
   )
   order by orderby
end if;
end$$
```

I've tried nested if, but that didn't seem to work, and i had problems with stored procedure and functions inside as well, but maybe you have some ideas, suggestions, solutions?

Comment: You should perform a left join between task and comment table.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. :-)

Comment: Cool, i'll make that the answer then we can close this question

Answer (score 0):

Your sql statement is performing an inner join, you should perform a left join between the task and comment table, which will bring back all tasks with comments iro if there are comments or not, meaning tasks without comments will have blank/nullable values.